# ポケモンGOのように地図を表示したい

Tags: java, android, google-maps

道や建物の情報は残して，それらのデザインをカスタムする方法が探しても見つかりません．
どなたか知っている方がいましたらご教授お願いします．

androidアプリにて，自作デザインのmapを作成しようと考えております．

ポケモンGOの地図は現実に存在する建物や道路が反映されていますが，デザインがオリジナルな‌​ものなので，私も同じように，デザインを変‌​えて地図を作成しようと考えているのですが‌​，全くその方法の検討がつきません．なので‌​，建物の住所情報を片っ端から集めて，それ‌​らをジオコーディングしたものを，open‌​GLを用いて取得した現在地とリアルタイム‌​で描画しようと考えていますが，未だ構想段‌​階なのでコードは書いておりません．

[image: サンプル]

Answer (score 2):

ポケモンGoがこの手法を用いているかは分かりませんが、Google MapのスタイルをカスタマイズするAPIが提供されています。

マップのスタイル設定を開始する  |  Google Maps JavaScript API  |  Google Developers
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling

[Google Maps APIs Styling Wizard](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/)をちょっと触ってみると、カスタマイズできそうと思えるのではないでしょうか。

Comment: なるほど！ありがとうございます！試してみます！